# Spring Rest API maximum size HTTP POST

Tags: java, spring, rest

I currently have a Java Spring Rest API that enables images base64 to be uploaded to my server. Now I would like to know if there is a way I can limit the upload size so that people wont be able to upload 1GB and crash my server.

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 4):

For those using Spring Boot, consider setting the following parameters in your *application.properties* (or *application.yml*) file:

```
multipart.max-file-size=1Mb
multipart.max-request-size=10Mb
```

See [Common application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be configured on the web server level and not on the code level. For example in tomcat you can configure `maxPostSize` param present in server.xml to limit the size of Http POST request.

Comment: I already tried setting the maxPostSize in tomcat but this doesnt work. I think this is because im sending it with the headers application/json.

Comment: Doesn't matter what is the MIME type. If the size of the POST payload goes beyond the defined limit, the request should be dropped by tomcat.